# Add option in bitbucket CI/CD to remove old application version before deployment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using Bitbucket CI/CD for our deployment in our AWS Elastic beanstalk environment. Now Elastic beanstalk saves the application version before deployment and if your application version exceeds 1000 then it will throw error. Is it possible in CI/CD to delete the oldest application version before deployment?

I have enabled application lifecycle on elastic beanstalk but still, I am getting those errors.

Comment: You can do it in delete them in Beanstalk console, Application versions.